# replace specific columns on lines not starting with specific character in a text file

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
>long_name
AAC-TGA
>long_name2
CCTGGAA
```

And a list of column numbers: `2, 4, 7`. Of course I can have these as a variable like:

```
cols="2 4 7"
```

I need to replace every column of the rows that don't start with `>` with a single character, e.g an `N`, to result in:

```
>long_name
ANCNTGN
>long_name2
CNTNGAN
```

Additional details - the file has ~200K lines. All lines that don't start with `>` are the same length. Line indices will never exceed the length of the non `>` lines.

It seems to me that some combination of sed and awk must be able to do this quickly, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to link it all together.

E.g. I can use sed to work on all lines that don't start with a `>` like this (in this case replacing all spaces with `N`'s):

```
sed -i.bak '/^[^>]/s/ /N/g' input.txt
```

And I can use AWK to replace specific columns of lines as I want to like this (I think...):

```
awk '$2=N'
```

But I am struggling to stitch this together

Comment: You never need sed when you're using awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk, set i/o field separators to empty string so that each character becomes a field, and you can easily update them.

```
awk -v cols='2 4 7' '
BEGIN {
  split(cols,f)
  FS=OFS=""
}
!/^>/ {
  for (i in f)
    $(f[i])="N"
}
1' file
```

Also see [Save modifications in place with awk](/questions/16529716/save-modifications-in-place-with-awk).

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a list of replacement commands first and then pass them to `sed`

```
$ printf '2 4 7' | sed -E 's|[0-9]+|/^>/! s/./N/&\n|g'
/^>/! s/./N/2
 /^>/! s/./N/4
 /^>/! s/./N/7
$ printf '2, 4, 7' | sed -E 's|[^0-9]*([0-9]+)[^0-9]*|/^>/! s/./N/\1\n|g'
/^>/! s/./N/2
/^>/! s/./N/4
/^>/! s/./N/7

$ sed -f <(printf '2 4 7' | sed -E 's|[0-9]+|/^>/! s/./N/&\n|g') ip.txt
>long_name
ANCNTGN
>long_name2
CNTNGAN
```

Can also use `{}` grouping

```
$ printf '2 4 7' | sed -E 's|^|/^>/!{|; s|[0-9]+|s/./N/&; |g; s|$|}|'
/^>/!{s/./N/2;  s/./N/4;  s/./N/7; }
```

Comment: You can mix seds `-e` and `-f` one or more times and `-f` accepts the `-` as stdin, so `<<<'2 4 7' sed -E 's#\S+#s/./N/&\n#g' | sed -e '/^>/b' -f - file` will achieve the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk -v cols='2 4 7' '
    BEGIN { split(cols,c) }
    !/^>/ { for (i in c) $0=substr($0,1,c[i]-1) "N" substr($0,c[i]+1) }
1' file
>long_name
ANCNTGN
>long_name2
CNTNGAN
```